can I create SOQL or SOSL command to get content of a report?
I know nothing about SF. I want to get content - preferably as .csv - or a report that someone created for me. I do not have SF account. I have access to an integration account that I managed to connect to Power Automate. I am able to use PowerAutomate to list reports. I do not know if there are any PA actions that can be used to get the content of a report.
I hope that  SOQL or SOSL could do the job. I search the internet and trid
SELECT Id FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate WHERE OwnerId = ‘ID: ’00OSe000000fZLBMA2’

but it did not work. PowerAutomate complained
[{"message":"No search term found. The search term must be enclosed in braces.",
"errorCode":"MALFORMED_SEARCH"}]

So before I dive deep into this I have a question if  SOQL or SOSL could be used to get the content of a SalesForce report.

You can't use SOQL to get report content, you have to use the Reports/Dashboards REST API.
